# Bootstrap input-group and form-floating issue

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have this form in bootstrap modal:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="add-item" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="add-item-label" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="add-item-label">Добавление позиции</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <form action="{% url 'storage:add-item-in-supply' id %}" method="POST" class="form" novalidate>
        <div class="modal-body">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="input-group form-floating mb-3" id="item-datalist-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="item-datalist" placeholder="Позиция" name="item"
              type="text" list="items" autocomplete="off">
            <label for="item-datalist">Позиция</label>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="clear-input" title="Очистить">
              <i class="fa fa-eraser"></i>
            </button>
            <datalist id="items" placeholder="Позиция">
              {% for i in add_item_in_supply_form.fields.item.queryset %}
                <option data-value="{{ i.id }}" value="{{ i }}"></option>
              {% endfor %}
            </datalist>    
          </div>
          <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            {{ add_item_in_supply_form.count }}
            <label for="full_number">Кол-во</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Отменить</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WOQH.png)

when #item-datalist is focused, label hiding. How i can repair it?

I tried to use z-index=999 for #item-datalist and change positions of #item-datalist and #items. When i try to separate input-group and form-floating classes:

```html
<div class="input-group" id="item-datalist-group">
  <div class="form-floating mb-3">
  <input class="form-control" id="item-datalist" placeholder="Позиция" name="item"
    type="text" list="items" autocomplete="off">
   <label for="item-datalist">Позиция</label>
   </div>
   <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="clear-input" title="Очистить">
    <i class="fa fa-eraser"></i>
   </button>
   <datalist id="items" placeholder="Позиция">
    {% for i in add_item_in_supply_form.fields.item.queryset %}
      <option data-value="{{ i.id }}" value="{{ i }}"></option>
    {% endfor %}
  </datalist>    
</div>
```

i have this:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q2ES.png)

but label didn't hiding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solution. Just needs to separate form-floation and input-group. Like this:

```html
<div class="input-group flex-nowrap mb-3">
  <div class="form-floating w-100">
    <input class="form-control" id="item-datalist" placeholder="Позиция" name="item"
      type="text" list="items" autocomplete="off">
      <datalist id="items" placeholder="Позиция">
        {% for i in add_item_in_supply_form.fields.item.queryset %}
          <option data-value="{{ i.id }}" value="{{ i }}"></option>
        {% endfor %}
      </datalist>
    <label for="item-datalist">Позиция</label>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="clear-input" title="Очистить">
    <i class="fa fa-eraser"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve this is by modifying your HTML structure and CSS to separate the `form-floating` from the `input-group` and adjust their positioning and styling. Here's an example structure you might consider:

```
 <div class="input-group" id="item-datalist-group">
  <input class="form-control" id="item-datalist-1" placeholder="Позиция 1" name="item1" type="text" list="items" autocomplete="off">
   <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="clear-input-1" title="Очистить">
     <i class="fa fa-eraser"></i>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
 <input class="form-control" id="floatingInput1" placeholder="Позиция 1" list="items" autocomplete="off">
 <label for="floatingInput1">Позиция 1</label>
</div>

<div class="input-group" id="item-datalist-group">
 <input class="form-control" id="item-datalist-2" placeholder="Позиция 2" name="item2" type="text" list="items" autocomplete="off">
 <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="clear-input-2" title="Очистить">
<i class="fa fa-eraser"></i>
 </button>
</div>
 <div class="form-floating mb-3">
 <input class="form-control" id="floatingInput2" placeholder="Позиция 2" list="items" autocomplete="off">
<label for="floatingInput2">Позиция 2</label>
</div>

<datalist id="items" placeholder="Позиция">
  {% for i in add_item_in_supply_form.fields.item.queryset %}
   <option data-value="{{ i.id }}" value="{{ i }}"></option>
  {% endfor %}
</datalist>
```

you might need to adjust the CSS to position the floating label appropriately when the input is focused or has a value. You could use a combination of CSS selectors like `:focus`, `:valid`, or `:not(:placeholder-shown)` to control when the label should be visible or hidden based on the input state.

```
#floatingInput:focus~label,
#floatingInput:not(:placeholder-shown)~label {
 /* Your styling to position the label when the input is 
 focused or has a value */
}
```

Comment: In this case i got that form -

[screen](https://iili.io/JA0ObAG.png),

with two inputs for one datalist.

Comment: I checked your update and get this form - [screen](https://a.imgfoto.host/2023/12/21/Screenshot-2023-12-21-111751.png). I need one input for datalist with floating label and button in input group.